# Showing Error while using Migration tool 1.9 to 2.0

Tags: magento2-migration-tool

Currently i am using magento2.0.4 version . I want to migrate data from 1.9.0.1 version of magento . I have completed all steps for migartion tool .
After that i am geeting this error .

```
[2016-05-20 10:18:04][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: SalesIncrement Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[Migration\Exception] Integrity Check failed
```

Please help me to resolve this issue .